# Using Bootstrap instead of a table to show tabular data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

*I am very new to web development, so this is a bit of a noob question.*

The framework I am using does not work well with tables (or at least not the way I want).

But it does seem to work fine with Twitter Bootstrap.

**So, I am wondering, is it bad form/practice/evil to just replace tables with something like this?**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <compose view-model="box-vm" model.bind="box" repeat.for="box of shipment.boxes"/>
</div>
```

*The compose creates a `class="row"` for each box in my shipment.*

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. Anyone who tells you there are absolutes is doing you a tremendous disservice. After 20 years in this field, IMHO the only evil table is one used for layout, because nested tables are a PITA to maintain...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is bad practise (assuming the tables were being used correctly in the first place).

The tabular data structure is used for purposes beyond the simple visual rendering (such as by accessibility tools like screen readers).

This is even [warned about in the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html):

> Note. CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.